# Paging output from print statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm essentially trying to achieve this:

```
>>>print "SOME_VERY_LONG_TEXT" | more
```

Of course, it doesn't work in Python 2.7(IDLE).

Also, I tried [pager 1.2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pager/1.2)'s `page()` function,  but I don't know how to get it to work correctly.

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**

I found a lazy way, as follows:

```
import pydoc
pydoc.pager("SOME_VERY_LONG_TEXT")
```

Comment: Any reason why `python foo.py | more` wouldn't work?

Comment: @Aesthete: probably not.  `more` is a linux command line program for paging output, similar to `less` which is more popular.

Comment: IPython pages some output by default (like the docs when checked using `object??` syntax). However it doesn't page the expression values (they're fed through `pprint`, but don't go through the pager).

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the pydoc.pager!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing something terminal and os independent might be a bigger task.

But if you can get the height of the terminal then you can use something like this this
Assuming your input is a generator/list of line seperated text, or else you can call text.split('\n') before calling this function

```
def pagetext(text_lined, num_lines=25):
   for index,line in enumerate(text_lined):
       if index % num_lines == 0 and index:
           input=raw_input("Hit any key to continue press q to quit")
           if input.lower() == 'q':
               break
       else:
           print line
```

Also there is a [pager](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pager) module on pypy haven't used it but the author says it was supposed to be included in the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

Although a bit late, the following worked for me:

```
def less(data):
    process = Popen(["less"], stdin=PIPE)

    try:
        process.stdin.write(data)
        process.communicate()
    except IOError as e:
        pass
```

Comment: For future readers, you may turn strings into bytes, i. e., the `data` with `bytes(string, 'utf-8')`.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it as an external process. (You have to [be careful](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) with `shell=True`, though.)

```
import subprocess
longStr = 'lots of text here'
subprocess.call(['echo "'+longStr+'" | more'], shell=True)
```

Comment: If you are using less instead of more use less -R to get colored output. The -R option will display the "raw" control characters".